# How can I use GET and POST on the same form in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a project wiki using Django and python from CS50W and stuck at a point where i have to check for the title is it exist or not and if it exists i will give message and option to change the title or edit it, now this part is using GET method and if the topic does not exist it will set focus to textarea and user can ad information about the title and save it to new file now this uses methot=POST. If I write the following code my check works

createNewPage.html

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 20%">        
     <form id="newTitle" action="{% url 'save' %}" method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}        
            {% block newTitle %}
                <label>{{ newTitle_form.title.label }}</label>
                {{ newTitle_form.title }}          
            {% endblock %}
     </form>
        {% if messages %}
            <div id="messageDiv" class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                {% for message in messages %}                
                    {{ message }}                
                {% endfor %}         
            </div>        
        {% endif %}
        {% if messages %}
            <div class="h1 flex-container btn-save-placement" style="height: 0px; padding-top: 0px; margin-right: 0%">
                <div>
                    <a role="button" id="changeTopic" class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'new_topic' %}">Change</a>
                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'edit' pagetitle %}">Edit</a>
                </div>
            </div>  
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 20%; margin-top: 25px">
        {% block textArea %}
            <label>{{ newText_form.text.label }}</label>
            {{ newText_form.text }}
        {% endblock %}
    </div> 
    <div class="btn-save-placement flex-container" style="height: 48px; padding-top: 0px;">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'save' %}" type="submit" formmethod="POST">Save New Page</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        function blurFunction() {
            var newTitleText = document.getElementById("titleCheck");
            if (newTitleText.value !== null && newTitleText.value !== "") {
                document.getElementById("newTitle").requestSubmit();
            }                    
        }
    </script>
```

and if I change  from the 8th line to 35th line just above the  then check does not work but it saves new file. what can i change to get both working.

views.py

```
def save(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        searchPage = request.GET.get('title','')
        if(util.get_entry(searchPage) is not None):
            messages.info(request, 'The Page '  + searchPage +   ' Already Exists, Do You Want To Change It Or Edit It!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("new_topic_t", kwargs={'entry': searchPage}))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("new_topic_t", kwargs={'entry': searchPage}))
    else:
        title = request.POST["title"]    
        content = request.POST["text"]
        util.save_entry(title, content)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("generate_page", kwargs={'entry': title}))
```

forms.py

```
class newTitle(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label='New Page Title', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'id': 'titleCheck',
            'class': 'search', 
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Type Topic Title Here...',
            'onblur': 'blurFunction()',
            'value': ''
        }))
    
    text = forms.CharField(label='Enter Page Text', widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            'id': 'NewTopicText',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'rows': '14'
        }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
def save(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        searchPage = request.GET.get('title','')  # consider using snake_case
        if(util.get_entry(searchPage) is not None):
            messages.info(request, 'The Page '  + searchPage +   ' Already Exists, Do You Want To Change It Or Edit It!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("new_topic_t", kwargs={'entry': searchPage}))
        else:
            form = newTitle() # consider using PascalCase
            return render('createNewPage.html', context={'newText_form': form})
    else:
        form = newTitle(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           title = form.cleaned_data["title"]    
           content = form.cleaned_data["text"]
           util.save_entry(title, content)
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("generate_page", kwargs={'entry': title}))
        else:
            return render('createNewPage.html', context={'newText_form': form})  # will render errors in the html page
```

FYI, as per [PEP-8 guideline](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should name variables and method names snake_case and Class names PascalCase.

Comment: giving error AttributeError at /save
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: you are probably using `request.cleaned_data`, it won't work. Please use `form.cleaned_data`